# always run a php file for every request on nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I did run Apache for a few years, but I was not able to get something running on Apache. So now I use Nginx, but I can't get the rewriterule working like I want.

I wand to always run a PHP script (`/index.php`), if the file from the link exists and if not, but never return 404 (this is done by PHP). I need this to redirect because of security. The security settings are stored in a database, so I really need to this PHP script to run always as first.

In Apache I used the following configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
</Directory>
```

Comment: What configuration are you using now, and what is wrong with it?

Comment: Now I use 'try_files $uri /index.php', but if I go a existing file like domain.con/path/to/file.txt it returs the file. And I want to run a php script (/index.php) which looks if you have permission to thise file (it does more stuff but that's not important)

Comment: Does the `index.php` file require resource files, such as `.css`? If you really just want `nginx` to return one file, put the PHP block into `location /` and hardwire SCRIPT_FILENAME to `/path/to/index.php`.